# Polynomial interpolation with constraints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to create a polynomial interpolation using scipy functions. I get some functions created that go through all my data points (5 data points actually) but I would like to add a constraints on the minimum value. My code is the following :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([10, 25, 50, 75, 90])
y = np.array([5.7239,5.53,5.37,5.43,5.789])

poly = lagrange(x, y)
xpol = np.linspace(x[0], x[4],1000)
ypol = poly(xpol)

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='s', c='r')
plt.plot(xpol, ypol)
```

The plot I am getting is the following :
[image]

The thing is that the point (50, 5.37) should be the minimum of my parabola (see black line on the plot) and I do not know how to set this up with scipy. Thank you...

Comment: Do you need a polynomial passing through all points or a parabola?

Comment: Yes, I managed to do that, but I would like to add a constraint that will be the minimum of my parabola...

Answer (score 1):

Using scipy.lagrange you get a high order polynomial, not a parabola.

You may try [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```
def parabola(x, a, b, c):
    return (a * x + b) * x + c

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
params, _ = curve_fit(parabola, x, y)
print(params)

[ 2.52716219e-04 -2.52482511e-02  5.97428457e+00]
```

[image]

This is now a parabola, but the vertex is not on the point you require.

Another alternative is [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

```
def parabola_error(params):
    err = parabola(x, *params) - y
    return err.dot(err)            # Sum of squares

from scipy.optimize import minimize
res = minimize(parabola_error, x0=np.array([1,1,1]), method='bfgs')
print(res.x)

[ 2.52323815e-04 -2.52090387e-02  5.97365419e+00]
```

Practically the same result as curve_fit, but we can now add the location of the vertex as additional constraints using the `SLSQP` method, for example:

The vertex of a parabola is given by `x0=-b/(2a)`, `y0=c-b²/(4a)`:

```
vertex_x = x[2]     # As required
vertex_y = y[2]

def vertex_x_error(params):
    a, b, c = params
    return - b / (2 * a) - vertex_x        # Not squared!

def vertex_y_error(params):
    a, b, c = params
    return c - b * b / (4 * a) - vertex_y  # Not squared!

constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': vertex_x_error},
               {'type': 'eq', 'fun': vertex_y_error})

# Using previous result as the seed
res = minimize(parabola_error, x0=res.x, method='SLSQP', constraints=constraints)
print(res.x)

[ 2.32725662e-04 -2.32725662e-02  5.95181415e+00]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will rely on your useful answer to do the same with a lagrange polynomial, as the curb I want is a polynomial.

Comment: @Amaumox thanks for your answer. kindly I have a similar question, want to ask if you can help or guide in. How can I perform spline interpolation between the same points in the question, lets say pairs of (t,y), and a spline between every two points, with setting a constraint that y(y) can't exceed certain value